# Write into a GCS file with a csv DictWriter

Tags: python, csv, google-cloud-storage, apache-beam

I am trying to write CSV files in the Google Cloud Storage using the apache_beam.io.gcp.gcsio module.

```
with GcsIO().open(filename=filename, mode='w', mime_type='text/plain') as outf:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(outf, fieldnames=fieldnames, extrasaction='ignore')
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(rows)
```

fieldnames is a list of strings and rows is a list of dictionaries ready to be consumed by a DictWriter.

The last lines of the error are:

```
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\csv.py", line 143, in writeheader
    return self.writerow(header)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\csv.py", line 154, in writerow
    return self.writer.writerow(self._dict_to_list(rowdict))
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' [while running 'ParDo(WriteCSVToGCS)']
```

I have tried to open the GCS file with different mime types (`text/csv` or the default) but the error is always the same.

All the data that is passed to the DictWriter are strings, as they are supposed to be usually, but just encoding them into bytes before passing them to the DictWriter does not correct the error.

This same code works well using an `io.StringIo` object as `outf`, so it really seems like an issue with using the `gcsio` object.

Comment: To clarify, are you looking to extract the contents of a `csv` file (hosted either locally or in GCS) into a `PCollection`?

Comment: I am actually looking to write the "results" of a pipeline into a CSV file. I am using now the google-cloud-storage library but I thought using only the apache-beam methods would be more efficient. Unfortunately it seems that the mime type is not being taken into account by the GcsIO class and therefore can't use a "text" writer like csv.DictWriter. Unless I am doing something else wrong.